# Values get overwritten in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making chat app and storing the messages in firebase and this is my structure:

```
{
 "1405093" : {
 "172341" : {
  "bot" : {
    "msg" : [ {
      "msg" : "hi",
      "timestamp" : "12:09:02"
    }, {
      "msg" : "bye",
      "timestamp" : "12:11:03"
    } ]
  },
  "consultant" : {
    "msg" : "Hi"
  },
  "resolved" : false,
  "user" : {
    "module" : "",
    "msg" : [ {
      "msg" : "hi",
      "timestamp" : "12:09:01"
    }, {
      "msg" : "bye",
      "timestamp" : "12:11:01"
    } ]
  }
},
"172351" : {
  "bot" : {
    "msg" : [ {
      "msg" : "hi",
      "timestamp" : "12:09:02"
    }, {
      "msg" : "bye",
      "timestamp" : "12:11:03"
    } ]
  },
  "consultant" : {
    "msg" : "Hi"
  },
  "resolved" : true,
  "user" : {
    "module" : "",
    "msg" : [ {
      "msg" : "hi",
      "timestamp" : "12:09:01"
    }, {
      "msg" : "bye",
      "timestamp" : "12:11:01"
    } ]
  }
}}
```

And here is my code

```
if(method === "addUser&Bot")
{
    umsg=data.umsg;
    bmsg=data.bmsg;
    ref.child(user+"/"+ticket_id).set({
        "user":{
            "msg":umsg,
            "module":""
        },
        "bot":{
             "msg":bmsg
        },
        "consultant":{
            "msg":"Hi"
        },
        "resolved":false
    });
    data={"name":user,"id":ticket_id}
    res.json(data);
}
```

As You can see I'm using set function and that's because of the field like 172341 which is actually a ticket_no which will always be unique and I don't want the randomly generated values created by firebase. So the problem is, this works great for the first time when the ticket_no is new but when again I'm sending a message the previous messages are overwritten. So how do I write a code that handles the new ticket_no and messages and also the messages that are sent afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only update the values that you're passing to the database, and leave anything you're not passing unmodified, use `update(...)` instead of `set(...)`:

```
ref.child(user+"/"+ticket_id).update({
    "user":{
        "msg":umsg,
        "module":""
    },
    "bot":{
         "msg":bmsg
    },
    "consultant":{
        "msg":"Hi"
    },
    "resolved":false
});
```

This will write only the `user`, `bot`, `consultant`, and `resolved` properties, and leave any other properties unmodified. But it will overwrite the complete value of the `user`, `bot`, `consultant`, and `resolved` properties. If you want to do a deep update, you can specify the precise path of what you want to update:

```
ref.child(user+"/"+ticket_id).update({
    "user/msg": umsg,
    "user/module": "",
    "bot/msg": bmsg,
    "consultant/msg": "Hi",
    "resolved":false
});
```

This last statement will write/update only the precise paths indicated, and leave everything else unmodified.

Comment: Is there any use case for `.set` in the Realtime Database? I've found that `.update` writes new nodes as well as updates existing nodes. I've also accidently deleted my entire database more than once using `.set`!

Comment: They serve different purposes. But it's definitely important to remember that `ref.set(...)` replaces whatever is at `ref`, while `ref.update({...})` does that one level lower.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen since every time a new message will come from user,bot and the consultant, i want them to be added but using update will overwrite the previous messages

Comment: since i'm storing array of msg and timestamp in usr/msg and bot/msg,I just want to append new  msg and timestamp together in that array